# How can I get all user options?

Tags: options

The codex has a function called `get_user_option()` but it requires me to pass the name of the option. Is there a wp function to retrieve all user options? I just need to see a list of all options set for a specific user. The only other similar function I found is `get_alloptions()` but that has been deprecated.

Comment: You can use [get_user_meta($user_id)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get all the meta for the user by using get_user_meta function

```
$all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( [user ID] );
echo "<pre>";
print_r( $all_meta_for_user );
```

Comment: Adding a `echo "<pre">;` before the `print_r()` can improve readability. :)

Comment: Thanks. I failed to realize that get_user_meta would retrieve all options.